# Asp.net MVC Dependency Injection in generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Currently I'm using DI and IoC to control some parts of my website. I don't know alot about it, but I've been trying to understand it by using. I'm using **StructureMap**

My controllers have the following Contructor

```
    IDbContext _db;

    public PagesController(IDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work immediatly, so I've created the following dependency

`x.For<IDbContext>().Use<ContextDb>();`

*Confusing enough, I've called the application "Context" -> hence `ContextDb` (don't confuse it with `DbContext` or `IDbContext`)*

Allright, now my problem. In the `Global.asax` file I decided I wanted to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, so I went and added the following:

`DbDatabase.SetInitializer<IDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<IDbContext>));`

Obviously this isn't working, `IDbContext` is an interface, and the dependency rules decide what implementation is used. So the only way to make this work is to use the following:

`DbDatabase.SetInitializer<ContextDb>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ContextDb>));`

However, that kinda defeats the purpose of this dependency injection right? How could I solve this?

Comment: What is DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges?

Comment: I'm using a code-first approach in development for my website. So when I change a Model, the MVC Framework drops the Database and creates it again; the structure of the table depending on how the models look.

Comment: `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` sounds scary :-)

Comment: Yeah it is xD But I only use it in development, and it accepts a seed so you can populate the database automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the ContextDB class into Web.Config and use ConfigurationManager to get it or some Configuration File and set the Activator to call it on Global.asax.cs like the code below:

```
String configString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDBContextType"];
IDBContext db = (IDBContext)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(configString));
```

That would keep the purpose of this dependency injection.

Hope it helps!!!